# Pourquoi l'acronyme anglais COVID a-t-il été directement intégré à la langue française?

Tags: terminologie, anglicismes, néologismes, emprunts, acronymes

En 1982 ou 1983, le terme *SIDA* est apparu dans la langue française, dans laquelle il s'est progressivement installé, perdant assez rapidement ses majuscules (d'abord *Sida*, puis assez tôt *sida*).

On peut deviner que le *COVID-19* suivra un parcours similaire : déjà le [Robert 2021](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/culture/livres/covid-au-masculin-et-sans-majuscule-dans-le-petit-robert-2022_4618473.html) propose *covid*, sans majuscule et sans le suffixe numéral, et *Covid-19* pour un usage plus spécifique.

Mais outre ce suffixe en chiffres, une autre différence notable existe entre le sida et le covid : le premier était construit sur une traduction de l'acronyme anglais (AIDS <sup>1</sup>), alors que le second est un emprunt intégral de l'acronyme anglais.

Plusieurs langues semblent montrer ce contraste dans l'intégration des deux termes. Qu'est-ce qui a provoqué cette différence ? Un simple hasard ? Le relativement peu de temps disponible pour forger un terme face à la rapide progression de la maladie partout dans le monde ? Le besoin d'une désignation homogène dans les diverses langues de l'Union Européenne, peut-être plus présent aujourd'hui qu'au début des années '80 ? L'omniprésence accrue de la langue anglaise suffirait-elle à expliquer ce glissement ?

---

1. <sub>L'usage des majuscules est [majoritairement maintenu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym#Pronunciation-dependent_style_and_case) encore aujourd'hui en anglais.</sub>

Comment: Connaissez-vous les statistiques à propos de l'usage des termes en la population générale à la temps de leur adoption?

Comment: @Geneviève Je ne connais pas les statistiques, et ne sais pas non plus quelle importance elles auraient pu jouer dans la décision finale des experts. A priori, j'aurais tendance à croire que le flot terminologique dans ces cas de maladies va principalement des experts vers la population générale, mais je ne suis pas du tout expert en ce sujet et mon opinion n'est pas informée.

Comment: Sur la question un peu accessoire des majuscules sur AIDS, je suppose cela évite la confusion avec le mot *aid* au pluriel (problème qu'on n'a pas en français avec sida).

Comment: On est passé à coté de la ***macovi*** (*Ma*ladie du *co*rona*vi*rus) ou peut-être de la ***mavicour*** (*Ma*ladie du *vi*rus à *cour*onne)...

Comment: @jlliagre De mon côté de l'Atlantique, on n'est du moins pas passé à côté du féminin, et malgré un an d'exposition quotidienne, je ne réussis pas à m'y habituer (la finale en -id y est pour beaucoup: David, caïd). Bien heureux d'avoir maintenant une officialisation européenne pour excuser mon usage du masculin, qui fait grincer quelques dents ici.

Comment: Oui, aussi:  polaroïd, tabloïd, celluloïd et kid. Ici, même les plus zélés champions du féminin n'ont pas encore osé ***la covid longue***...

Comment: Ah si, on en trouve...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je pense que la réponse tient à trois choses.

Avant tout, la prédominance de l'anglais dans les médias, dans les informations que consomment le public et, surtout, dans toute la communication scientifique, a augmenté sensiblement en 40 ans. Par exemple, en 1980, quand le sida commence à être l'objet de recherches, 4,6% des articles scientifiques mondiaux sont encore publiés en français ([Hamel, 2007](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-dominance-of-English-in-the-international-and-Hamel/e4e248576d802bf079905b987a58302bfdbe8ac9)); aujourd'hui, ils sont bien en-dessous d'1% ([Stephen et al, 2020](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339377437_Performance_and_Structures_of_the_German_Science_System_2020_Studien_zum_deutschen_Innovationssystem)) et on peut estimer que dans un domaine comme la médecine, tous les chercheurs francophones de renom publient seulement en anglais. L'accès à l'information est aujourd'hui mondialisé et énormément de journalistes consultant directement des sources en anglais. Pour toutes ces raisons, toute discussion sur le Covid dans le monde anglophone a nécessairement eu immédiatement des influences linguistiques sur la discussion en français.

La seconde différence est effectivement la temporalité. Pour le sida, il se passe plus d'un an entre le premier rapport clinique (juin 1981) et l'utilisation systématique du terme *AIDS* par le CDC américain (septembre 1982) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIV/AIDS#History)). Dans le cas du Covid, il se passe un mois entre la première étude (janvier) et le nommage "COVID-19" par l'OMS (11 février 2020). Avec une diffusion publique immédiate de ces informations au niveau mondial à partir de janvier 2020, le temps de réaction des institutions terminologiques francophones était complètement dépassé.

On pourra dire que certains termes anglophones ont rapidement trouvé des équivalents francophones sans besoin de l'intervention de terminologues (p.ex., *distance learning* devient *apprentissage distanciel*), mais il s'agit de calques morphologiques dont l'adaptation française est pratiquement automatique. Les autres sont soit restés non-adaptés, sauf phonologiquement (*R0*, *PCR*), soit existaient déjà en français (*pandémie*, *confinement*, *variant*, etc.).

La troisième différence, peut-être la plus intéressante, tient au fait que le sida a, il me semble, été d'abord particulièrement discuté dans le monde nord-américain (même si le virus a été isolé par des chercheurs français), et a donc fait son apparition publique en français au Canada plutôt qu'en Europe. Or, on sait que les autorités québécoises sont particulièrement attachées à l'établissement d'équivalents français aux termes anglais. C'est ce qui s'est passé avec le sida à la fin de 1981: le Ministère canadien de la Santé voulait diffuser un communiqué basé sur des informations du CDC d'Atlanta qui mentionnait le terme *AIDS*. Le Ministère voulait, à son habitude, diffuser le communiqué tant en français qu'en anglais et a donc fait appel à une terminologue du Bureau de la traduction du Secrétariat d'État, Sylvie DuPont, pour trouver un équivalent à *AIDS*: c'est à elle que nous devons la traduction française et l'acronyme *SIDA*. Elle le raconte dans un texte de 2004: [Petite histoire du terme « sida »](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9g6B6_WsiKfM.html). C'est à mon avis ce passage précoce par le Québec qui a fait la plus grande différence ici: quand le sida a commencé à être discuté largement en France, l'équivalent était déjà disponible.

Comment: 1. Je mettrais plutôt *variant* dans la catégorie "existait déjà en français". 2. Un mot qui a fait polémique est *cluster*, largement utilisé par les media. Des voix se sont élevées pour qu'on lui substitue *foyer (épidémique)* mais sans succès.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai plutôt l'impression que ça aurait dû être l'inverse : des voix auraient dû s'élever pour qu'on ne substitue **pas** *cluster* à *foyer*. De mémoire, il me semble que lorsqu'on a commencé à parler de l'épidémie, même les médias utilisaient *foyer* avant de changer pour un terme qui devaient leur paraitre plus... Moderne, branché?

Comment: @Sacha Non, les media ont tout de suite parlé de clusters. https://www.rtl.fr/actu/bien-etre/coronavirus-qu-est-ce-qu-un-cluster-7800193430 https://mediateur.radiofrance.com/non-classe/10-cluster/

Comment: @jlliagre Je trouve quelques cas d'utilisation de *foyer* (surtout *foyer de contamination* et *foyer épidémique*) avant mars 2020, mais également durant toute l'année 2020 donc j'imagine que ça doit être des exceptions.
Ca m'a assez surpris (et agacé), surtout au début, car l'équivalent français existe et est relativement connu. Ca mériterait une question similaire à celle-ci, je la poserai dans la journée si j'ai le temps...

Comment: Cette discussion sur *cluser/foyer* est un peu à côté du sujet, mais comme je trouve la trouve intéressante, je mentionne la version québécoise de la chose, qui privilégie le plus souvent «éclosion à tel endroit» plutôt que «foyer (épidémique)/cluster à tel endroit».

Comment: Merci @jlliagre, effectivement, *variant* plutôt dans la catégorie "existait déjà". J'ai corrigé!